# Selenium file upload fails with error: "POST did not match a known command"

Tags: python, selenium

When I attempt to upload a file with selenium 3.3.0 I get the following error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: POST (...) did not match a known command

The code that triggers this exception is:

```
file_field.send_keys(os.getcwd() + '/myfile.txt')
```

What does this error mean?

Here's the entire code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('file://' + os.getcwd() + '/form.html')
file_field = driver.find_element_by_id('file')
file_field.send_keys(os.getcwd() + '/myfile.txt')
```

Here's form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug in Selenium. As a workaround, add `driver._is_remote = False` after the `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` line.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42770761/373915 for details.