# Can't upload file using Selenium with Python. POST POST /session/b90ee4c1-ef51-4cc0-8543-dfd76c7a151d/file did not match a known command

Tags: python, selenium, post, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to upload a file to this website

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

my_mail = "email@yahoo.com"

driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts")
driver.get("https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/OPUS/")
assert "OPUS" in driver.title

driver.find_element_by_name("uploadfile").send_keys("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\popo\\uhc30010.15d")

email = driver.find_element_by_name("email_address")
email.send_keys(my_mail)

driver.find_element_by_name("Static").click()
```

but I am getting this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/b90ee4c1-ef51-4cc0-8543-dfd76c7a151d/file did not match a known command

Answer (score 2):

sorry this was inadvertently broken. It will be fixed in the next release:

[557a114](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/557a11404ebeae263dd0ec83e4b262190cf0d52d)

As a workaround, you can set the `_is_remote` property of the webdriver to False after you create it:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver._is_remote = False
```