# Uploading a picture with selenium is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload an image using selenium in python. I tried all the answers available on the internet but nothing seems to work for me.

Versions:

Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0

selenium-3.141.0-py2.7

Error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/36d51528-01bd-4fa7-b4c8-ea96521421df/file did not match a known command
```

[Can't upload file using Selenium with Python. POST POST /session/b90ee4c1-ef51-4cc0-8543-dfd76c7a151d/file did not match a known command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754877/cant-upload-file-using-selenium-with-python-post-post-session-b90ee4c1-ef51-4)

[Selenium file upload fails with error: "POST did not match a known command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734328/selenium-file-upload-fails-with-error-post-did-not-match-a-known-command)

```
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "templateName").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "templateName").send_keys("Test")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "type").click()
        dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "type")
        dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'test']").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "file-upload").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/picture.png")
```

I expect to upload the image using selenium

Comment: Can you share the html dom of the object. if you could provide the url of the page that would be even more helpful as well?

Comment: self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "file-upload").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/picture.png"),here id should be of "<input" tag,then only it will upload properly.